# ConsoleApplication/Service Takes 40 Seconds to start

Tags: c#, windows, .net-3.5, windows-services

I basically have the below:

```
partial class OperationWindowsService : ServiceBase
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
Console.WriteLine("Starting app.");
//...build opservice
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("interactive");
   var task = opservice.StartConsole(args);
}else
 {
    ServiceBase.Run(opservice);
    logger.LogInfo("ServiceBase.Run Called");
 }

}
//... normal onstart overrriden
}
```

When run as a console application or run as a windows service on my box it starts up instantly.  On some windowsxp box's it's deployed to it takes 45 seconds before "Starting app." or any logging appears.  We doubt it has anything to do with speed since some boxes are the same hardware/image.

Can anyone give me insighte into why it would take 45 seconds to start an appication before the first line get's hit?

Comment: *crazy idea:* JIT compilation?

Comment: I was worried it had something to do with the service, and it turned out it had more to do with which dlls it was using

Answer (score 2):

ProcessMonitor was exceptionally helpful to look at what an exe does before it does anything.

Turned out:
I had loaded RSACryptoServiceProvider which loaded a dll which loaded another which somehow tries to certify itself via a network connection.
The box it is running on is locked down and timeouts network connections causing the delay in loading the dll.

Fix:
Set this in your app.config-

```
<runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

For more see this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/05/13/asp-net-hang-authenticode-signed-assemblies.aspx